# Spring Elasticsearch - bulk save multiple indices in one line?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have multiple documents with different index name that bulk saves in elasticsearch:

```
public void bulkCreateOrUpdate(List personUpdateList, List addressUpdateList, List positionUpdateList) {
    this.operations.bulkUpdate(personUpdateList,Person.class);
    this.operations.bulkUpdate(addressUpdateList, Address.class);
    this.operations.bulkUpdate(positionUpdateList, Position.class);
}
```

However, is this still possible to be optimized by calling just a single line, saving multiple list of different index types?

Comment: Which client are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

The [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) certainly allows for it.

This is a valid call

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"index_1"}}
{"data":"data"}
{"index":{"_index":"index_2"}}
{"data":"data"}
```

How does your Java Client deal with it ... I am not sure.

## Solution

- #### [Java client - Bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html)

This could be done:

```java
BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();

br.operations(op -> op           
        .index(idx -> idx            
            .index("index_1")       
            .id("1")
            .document(document)
        )
    );

br.operations(op -> op           
        .index(idx -> idx            
            .index("index_2")       
            .id("1")
            .document(document)
        )
    );
```

- #### [Java Rest Client - Bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html)

This could be done this way:

```java
BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest(); 

request.add(new IndexRequest("index_1").id("1")  
        .source(XContentType.JSON,"data", "data"));
request.add(new IndexRequest("index_2").id("1")  
        .source(XContentType.JSON,"data", "data"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Data Elasticsearch :

The `ElasticsearchOperations.bulkXXX()` methods take a `List<IndexQuery>` as first parameter. You can set an index name on each of these objects to specify in which index the data should be written/updated. The index name taken from the last parameter (either the entity class or an `IndexCoordinates` object) is used in case that no index name is set in the `IndexQuery`.

Comment: it takes a List<IndexQuery> but only a class/IndexCoordinates. Does this mean, it is not possible to do bulkxxx with multiple indices in just one line/request?

Comment: I just answered that exact question.

Comment: Based on my understanding on your comments, the last parameter in bulkUpdate (IndexCoordinates) is optional. Is this correct? But as I checked the implementation, it is indeed required. 

And also, UpdateQuery does not have setter/method to specify the index. May I know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: It is not optional. It is used on building the request, when there is no specific value set in an `IndexQuery` object from the list. The builder classes for the `IndexQuery` and `UpdateQuery` have methods to set the index name.