# Spring Elasticsearch - bulk upsert/update multiple indices in one line?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an existing method that upsert/update documents SEPARATELY in elasticsearch:

```
 @Override
  public void bulkUpdate(List<T> objectList) {
    if (objectList.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    List<UpdateQuery> updateList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T st : objectList) {
      UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(st.getId())
          .withDocument(this.operations.getElasticsearchConverter().mapObject(st))
          .withDocAsUpsert(true)
          .build();
      updateList.add(updateQuery);
    }

    this.operations.bulkUpdate(updateList,
        this.operations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(this.entityClass));
  }
```

and for calling the method:

```
public void callUpdate (){

    personRepository.bulkUpdate(personList);
    addressRepository.bulkUpdate(addressList);
    phoneNumberRepository.bulkUpdate(phoneNumberList);
}
```

However, is this still possible to be optimized by calling just a single line, updating/upserting multiple list of different index types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Elasticsearch - bulk save multiple indices in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444019/spring-elasticsearch-bulk-save-multiple-indices-in-one-line)

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. Can you provide an example please?